# Is there a standard measurement of 2-dimensional precision?

Tags: measurement-error, measurement, precision

Suppose a gun is fired at the bullseye of a target a specific number of times.

Ignoring the accuracy (e.g. all the shots are well to the left and above the bullseye), is there a standard way of expressing the precision (i.e. how closely they cluster together) and the confidence of that value (based on the number of shots)?

- Input: N (x,y) coordinates with arbitrary origin.
- Output: precision, confidence.

Comment: One standard definition of precision is the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix.  It's not a single number because it needs to account for the precision in all dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply sum the variances of x and y coordinates to represent the precision.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [intra-cluster distance](https://medium.com/@Suraj_Yadav/understanding-intra-cluster-distance-inter-cluster-distance-and-dun-index-a-comprehensive-guide-a8de726f5769), which is the average distance between any two points in the cluster.

One way to measure the confidence of this value would be to [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) the intra-cluster distance. To do this, say you have N shots. Then take a bootstrap sample by randomly drawing N samples from the N shots with replacement and calculate the intra-cluster distance for the bootstrap sample. Repeat this a large number of times (at least 1000). The variation of the bootstrapped intra-cluster distances can be used to estimate a confidence interval.